# Hide a label created by jQuery Validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that I validate using jQuery Validation. The problem I'm having is that after a user interacts with a textbox jQuery Validation inserts a label under it which pushes everything below it down. Here is my HTML code for the form

```
<form id="addForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="first">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first" id="first" placeholder="First Name">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="last">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last" id="last" placeholder="Last Name">
 </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
</form>
```

Validation script

```
$('#addForm').validate({
    rules: {
        first: {
            required: true
        },
        last: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-danger');
        $(element).closest('.form-control').removeClass('form-control-success').addClass('form-control-danger');
    },
    success: function (element) {
        element.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-danger');
    }

});
```

I tried adding

```
element.closest('.error').hide();
```

to the success function, but that doesn't do anything. 
I tried adding an empty errorPlacement function

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {

}
```

and it somewhat works. However, it stops the function where the error highlight around the textbox gets cleared once the error is fixed.

Here is a link to JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/q9bppocn/

Comment: Look at the answer of @Sparky which is more cleaner and works fine.  Here you have the doc of jQuery validate : https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/ that may help you understand the different options :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the plugin automatically toggles the message, you should not have to "remove" the error.

You should simply be using `unhighlight` with `highlight`. They are complementary functions, which when working together, will properly toggle the error.  The `success` function is only meant for leveraging the `label` element whenever it's normally hidden.

```
highlight: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-danger');
    $(element).closest('.form-control').removeClass('form-control-success').addClass('form-control-danger');
},
unhighlight: function(element) {
    $(element).closest('.form-group').addClass('has-success').removeClass('has-danger');
    $(element).closest('.form-control').addClass('form-control-success').removeClass('form-control-danger');
}
```

**DEMO**:  [jsfiddle.net/vboantcf/](https://jsfiddle.net/vboantcf/)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to remove the label on success.

**JS**

```
$('#addForm').validate({
    rules: {
        first: {
            required: true
        },
        last: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-danger');
        $(element).closest('.form-control').removeClass('form-control-success').addClass('form-control-danger');
    },
    success: function (element) {
      element.remove();
    }

});
```

Here's a [jsFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/d4xb1rcx/)

Comment: With your solution, the error stays red and never clears despite the message being removed.  Since the plugin automatically takes care of the error messages, this is a hack.

Comment: @Sparky True. I didn't see it. Your solution is more cleaner :)